# C# Apply Interface to a Form Class

Tags: c#, interface

How can I apply an Interface to a form class

```
partial class Form1 : Form, InterfaceA
```

Is this correct?

Basically I would like to implement an Interface on a form. 
How To ....

Answer (score 6):

A Form is just a class (that subclasses System.Windows.Forms.Form), so yes - standard syntax  is fine, as you have it.

Edit: As to your partial class part of the question, no, you need only declare that you implement the interface once. From MSDN...

> If any of the parts are declared abstract, then the entire type is considered abstract. If any of the parts are declared sealed, then the entire type is considered sealed. *If any of the parts declare a base type, then the entire type inherits that class*.

Remember, there's no magic in forms or partial classes. C#/.Net is one of the few Microsoft projects that's wizardry free - it really does tend to behave the way you think it should.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - a form is just a class at the end of the day

Comment: Hmmm, except that inheritance doesn't work for visual elements (in Visual Studio) . Because it's done by on teh fly codegeneration not declarative inheritance... This is well-known, the technical reason is well-knowm, but it is not fixed in 2008 and MS don't seem to care. BE WARNED!

Comment: Except inheritance does work. To access controls on a user control / form from a child, the control must be declared protected or public using the 'Modifiers' in the property editor, or in the .designer.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

When working with partial classes in C#, either:

- any declaration with the ':' operator must specify exactly the same baseclass and interfaces
- specifying baseclass and interfaces on one of the declarations will suffice

To make life easier for yourself, add the interface specs in only one place (without checking I suspect this is in the designer class part by default when working with the WinForms designer).